# const qualifier accepted in ctor declaration/definition (llvm bug?)

Tags: c++, gcc, constructor, constants, clang

My compiler (actually `Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)`) accepts (compile) that code :

```
class X {
private:
  int i;
public:
  const X() { cout << "here" << endl; i=0; }
  void f() const {}
  void g() {}
};

int main() {
  const X x;
  x.f();
  //  x.g();
  X y;
  y.f();
  y.g();
}
```

It works as if there is no `const` qualifier leading the ctor definition. I tried `-Wall`, `-pedantic` different kind of standard's activations, always the same... So :

- did I missed something ? I wasn't able to find that it is syntactically correct in the latest standard…
- is this a bug of gcc/llvm ? It seems that `gcc/llvm` silently ignore the `const`.
- is this a feature that I missed, and for which my example is not able to demonstrate its usefulness?

Note: gcc 3.4.3 don't compile it, nor gcc 4.4.5.

Comment: Hmm that doesn't seem to allow exception-specifications. It is different in the latest draft for C++1y; which explicitly allows exception-specifications and attributes, but still seems not to allow type-specifiers such as `const`.

Comment: Submitted a [bugreport](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=17898).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell this does not look like valid syntax, the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) section `12.1` *Constructors* paragraph *1* says:

> Constructors do not have names. A special declarator syntax is used to declare or define the constructor.
>   The syntax uses:
>
> > — an optional decl-specifier-seq in which each decl-specifier is either a function-specifier or constexpr,
> >
> > — the constructor’s class name, and
> >
> > — a parameter list

and we can see from section `7.1.2` *Function specifiers* are as follows:

```
function-specifier:
 inline
 virtual
 explicit
```

Via Ali in the [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19935868/const-qualifier-accepted-in-ctor-declaration-definition-llvm-bug/19936210#comment29669891_19935868) a [bug report](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=17898) was filed for this it was confirmed and resolved.

Comment: right! I misread it! In fact I was lost in *ptr-declarator* definition and I missed the *function-specifier*. My version of the draft seems not to be exactly the same as yours. Thanks! One more: "would you qualify it a bug or an unknown g++ feature?"

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I added a link to the version I am using and I checked out an older version and the language is pretty similar. this [previous thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents) is a good resource for different versions of the standard.